# How to pass the path name to sed

Tags: regex, sed

I tried to pass the search pattern as path to sed, but it is not taking the path name. It is showing the error as "sed: command garbled". Here is the used code,

```
sed -e "/$node/s/^/#/" /etc/inittab > /etc/inittab.new && sudo mv /etc/inittab.new /etc/inittab
```

Here i am passing the search pattern as "opt/product/BETA/scp_install/bin/startBETAscp", and i am getting the error as "sed: command garbled: /(opt/product/BETA/scp_install/bin/startBETAscp)/s/^/#/"

Please suggest me, how to use the content of the variable into the search.

Comment: it's because of `/`'s in the search pattern..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with sed you can check the regex match by `/pattern/`, the `/` could be char other than `/ (slash)`. the format is `\@pattern@` (here `@` is the example). So your line would be:

```
sed "\@$node@s/^/#/" ....
```

#### add how it worked:

```
kent$ (master|✔) v="a/b/c"

kent$ (master|✔) sed "\@$v@s/^/#/" <<< "foo  
dquote> a/b/c"
foo
#a/b/c
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of this trick `\@` + `@`. I see it could be anything else: `sed "\~$node~s/h/H/"`, etc.

Comment: Getting the error as Unrecognized command: \@opt/product/BETA/scp_install/bin/startBETAscp@/s/^/#/

Comment: @sivakumarV see the test in answer, how it worked. you added an extra `/` between `@` and `s/...` please make sure you run the correct command before reporting "doesn't work"

Comment: @fedorqui usually `/.../` is enough, I don't know the slash there could be other chars either, until about last year, I had a very similar problem as OPs. I thought there should be an option, and finally found in  man page.